# Atmega 328P U crash on 5V/1A

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328

Atmega 328PU crash on 5v/1A. Why? It works on 5V/400ma but when i switch it to 5V/1A power it crash. Any idea or solution for this?

Comment: sure, don't use the defective power supply that causes crashes

Comment: You're asking why, but you're providing no details to enable us to answer your question. There's no reason a more powerful supply should crash your ATMega328P, so it's probably caused by a faulty supply or some other problem (which we can't help you with because you have not told us anything about your setup).

Comment: Thanks guys, yea the power supply was foulty. i get a new one and its working fine. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing wong, if your power supply is trustworthy enough, then , if u even provide 100000 Amps of current with 5 volt,
your IC won't burn, in your case , it burnt because your power supply seems to be defective, and please check the voltage of the power supply which is supposed to be defective, so it output more than 5 volts burning or crashing your ic...

Note:

I have personally worked with 5 volt 6 amp power supply which is very well precise and my ic is working full fledged without any problems.

Comment: yea the adapter was faulty. i get new one (5V/1A) and it's working fine. Thank you @Subha Jeet